# TFS/Project Server just one-side synchro

Tags: tfs, project-server

I installed the TFS/PS connector today, but the synchronization is just one-side!
Indeed, when I had a task from TFS, I can see it in PWA. But when I create a task from PWA or Project Professional, I can't see it into TFS.
What may be the problem?
Thanks a lot